# Download yahoo finance data stops in the middle of loop

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I have a piece of simple python code to download all Nasdaq daily stock data, roughly 3000+ stocks, but in the middle of the downloading it stopped until i press Enter key again in the Dos window.

python myScript.py all_nasdaq_stock_symbols.txt

```
ins = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

for line in ins:
    words = line.split()
    for aStock in words:
        # less painful, data from yahoo are inaccurate some times
        base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=";
        url = base_url + aStock;
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, aStock+".csv");
```

Why is this and how to solve it please ?

Comment: Take a look at the`pandas_datareader` package. It automates this exact task.

Answer (score 0):

ok, there's a limitation
you are limited to 2,000 calls/hour/IP to the public YQL Web service URL

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/